# Unexpected indeterminate outputs from verilog conditional operator

Tags: verilog

I have the following combinatorial assignment in a verilog module:

```
assign ififo_di = fetching_pc ? { 5'h02, 3'h7, 16'h8000 } : decoded_insn;
```

where `ififo_di` is an output, `fetching_pc` is a local register and `decoded_insn` is an input (which, in all my testing so far, is always set to 24'h000000).

And have a clock-triggered action that sets `fetching_pc` for a single cycle in specific circumstances.  The same block also provides synchronous reset and sets up a monitor for debugging purposes:

```
always @(posedge clk)
begin
    fetching_pc <= !reset & next_task_ready;
    if (reset)
    begin
     // reset registers
     $display ("ifetch reset");
     $monitor ("active: %b, task_loaded: %b, fetching_pc: %b, ififo_di: %b", active, task_loaded, fetching_pc, ififo_di);

     active <= 0;
     task_loaded <= 0;
    end
end
```

The test bench code that triggers these actions is:

```
@(posedge clk);
reset = 1;
@(posedge clk);
reset = 0;
@(posedge clk) #10;

next_task_channel = 3;
next_task_thread = 0;
next_task_ready = 1;

@(posedge clk) #10;

// at this point the ififo_di output is checked and the test fails
```

At the time the `next_task_ready` input is set to 1, the `reset` input is 0, and the internal registers `active` and `task_loaded` are both verified as containing 0 (although `task_loaded` is changed to 1 in the same cycle -- but altering this so that this change doesn't take place gives identical results).

My expectation is that when this happens, `ififo_di` will change from 000000h to 178000h, however what really happens (testing in icarus verilog) is this:

```
ifetch reset
active: 0, task_loaded: 0, fetching_pc: 0, ififo_di: 000000000000000000000000
ifetch reset
active: 0, task_loaded: 0, fetching_pc: 0, ififo_di: 000000000000000000000000
active: 0, task_loaded: 0, fetching_pc: 1, ififo_di: 000x0xxxx000000000000000
```

Why would the output by changing the bits that need to change to `x` rather than to 1 as expected?  I would understand if `fetching_pc` were `x`, but it's clearly being shown in the monitor output as 1, so what's going on here?

(updated: Eliminated some unnecessary code so that I can provide the entire `always` block as tested, thus showing all potentially-relevant content of the module.)

Comment: *And have a clock-triggered action that sets fetching_pc for a single cycle in specific circumstances* - and this is something that needs to be shown here, as the issue is clearly there.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - updated

Comment: As it is show - it should not "flicker". But I am still suspecting the stuff hiding behind the `// ...`

Comment: @EugeneSh. The flicker is caused by setting `task_loaded` to 1, which causes `fetching_pc` to return to 0, but I have also tested without this change and the issue persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it was from a surprising source -- the testbench code had an incorrectly defined connection for the `ififo_di` output:

```
wire ififo_di = 0;
```

The 1s produced were being merged with the zeros hardwired as the output and generating an indeterminate result; I would naturally have expected this to be an error condition, but it seems it isn't.